# Rails Case or Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a number of codes which all have different meanings e.g. "cancelled", "confirmed" etc and I store the code in the database. I want to make use of the word forms in a number of different places around my Rails app and wanted to know what people recommend for this to keep things as efficient as possible.

I have considered a case statement in my views but it will be repeated and I want to avoid logic in my views too. So I thought maybe a helper but should it be a case statement within the helper?

This is what I have so far in my relevant helper file:

```
def status_word(status)
  case status
  when 1
    puts "Cancelled"
  when 2
    puts "Confirmed"
  end
end
```

and I call it in my view as follows:

```
<%= status_word(1) %>
```

but nothing is outputted in my view. Can/should I use "put" here or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using `puts` incorrectly. It's for writing to standard output, not for returning a value from a method. You want `return`, or just let the value fall off the end of the method:

```
def status_word(status)
  case status
  when 1 then "Cancelled"
  when 2 then "Confirmed"
  end
end
```

With `puts` before each string, you're actually returning the return value of `puts`, which is  `nil`:

```
irb(main):001:0> puts "what"
what
=> nil
```

Comment: Tah very much - sorry new to Rails so still getting to grips with it ha ha - I will mark as correct when it allows me to. Cheers